# packer AWS which base images to choose for intel processors instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-20.04, amazon-ami, packer

When searching the official Ubuntu amis in AWS interface I see only -amd64- or -arm64- options.
I dont see any interl option (x86). How can I find the intel compatible base AMIs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a very simple way, amd64 is the 64 bits evolution of the x86 architecture, so for intel-based processors is the right platform.